# How can I verify my AirAsia booking made via an online travel agent on the AirAsia website?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, bookings, travel-agents, airasia

I booked a flight from China to Thailand using an online travel agent and have the air reservation number, E-Ticket number, and Airline Confirmation Number.

I want to verify this on AirAsia's website but according to [their help page on this topic](http://www.airasia.com/ask/template.do?id=515) I have to log in to my existing AirAsia account or create one with the email address I used to book the ticket. This seems to rely on me having booked the flight directly with AirAsia.

Am I missing something or can I not verify this flight directly with AirAsia and only with the online travel agent?

Comment: Yes it does but [it's not a full-fledged agent](http://www.onwardflights.com).

Comment: That's what [AirAsia says to do](http://www.airasia.com/ask/template.do?id=515): _ If you are not an AirAsia BIG member: Use the same email you entered when you made your booking to register here as an AirAsia BIG member. Upon successful registration, follow steps “1-6” above._

Comment: AirAsia doesn't at all seem to clarify that it will somehow know you're using the same email address even if you only gave it to some third party. My reading of the AirAsia site was that it implicitly expected you to have booked directly with them. In any case the process seemed to including agreeing to SPAM that you couldn't opt out of so I didn't proceed.

Comment: Have you checked on CheckMyTrip?

Comment: @hippietrail What is your flight number? Air Asia has several subdivions, so it is important

Comment: @Crazydre: My flight number is AK583

Comment: @hippietrail Contact the 24/7 chat service here, marking "AK" in "flight carrier code". I would, but obviously don't know your booking number http://www.airasia.com/my/en/live-chat.page

Answer (score 8):

I just called the Indian AirAsia call centre, who said that the website "should" recognise your E-mail address even if you didn't book directly through them. However, even if it doesn't, they said you can call them and tell them your e-ticket number, and they'd add it into their system.

It should be noted that this call centre, the only one open 24/7, is specialised in flights with a D7 flight code.

So, please let us know your exact flight number, so I can contact the proper department tomorrow. Air Asia has several subdivisions, so it might make a difference.